# Calculating unique words in a string

Tags: c#

I have a page called post summary.
Under this page, I want to count the total number of words and total number of unique words.
I managed to count the total number of words in the post successfully.
However, I do not know how I can count the unique words.

Eg: "I enjoyed school today very much."

Expected output:

```
Total word count: 6
Unique word count: 5
```

Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace empTRUST
{
    public partial class PostSummary : Form
    {
        string target_fbid;
        string fbStatus;

        public PostSummary(string target_fbid, string fbStatus)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.target_fbid = target_fbid;
            this.fbStatus = fbStatus;
        }

        private void PostSummary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label_totalwordcount.Text = fbStatus.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting unique word count of 5 from "I enjoyed school today very much"?

Comment: I think he meant unique letters

Comment: @Sam If he meant letters, it would be more than 5

Comment: Please explain your definition of 'word'

Comment: Please check your sample

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your example since there are no repeating words in `"I enjoyed school today very much"`. However, this is a naive approach which might work for you:

```
var allWords = text.Split();
int count = allWords.Length;  // 6
int unqiueCount = allWords.Distinct().Count();  // 6
```

It is naive because punctuation characters modify the result. So you might want to replace them in the first step:

```
var allWords = text.ToUpperInvariant().Replace(".", "").Replace(",","").Split(); // ...
```

Also, the case modifies the result, so you could compare case-insensitively if that is desired.

Comment: I think there is are `Char.IsLetter` and `Char.IsWhitespace` functions that can be used here.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: the thing is that we don't know what is a format of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Can use something like this:

```
"I enjoyed school school today very much.".Split(' ').Distinct()
```

This one returns `6`, even if there is "school" word that appears `2` times.

**EDIT**

if you need some custom comparison logic (say case insensitive) you may use [Distinct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb338049.aspx) where you can specify custom equality comparer.

Comment: `But. But but` would return 3, no?

Answer (score 0):

The first tought is:

```
public int GetUniqueWordsCount(string input)
{
    return input.Split(' ').GroupBy(s => s).Count();
}
```

If you would like a case insensitive solution you could add `.ToLower()` or `.ToUpper()` conversion to your group key selector. Also you may implement your own `IEqualityComparer` if you want some custom comparsion logic.